# how to distribute socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, load-balancing, distributed

Im using nodejs and socket.io to deliver a chat on my business app, but i want to distribute the deploy so i can have as many chat servers i want to balance the load of the traffic.

I try the load balance approach from nginx but that just do that balance the traffic but the communication between the socket.io serves its not the same, so one chat message send from user A to server S1 wont travel to user B on server S2.

There is any tool or approach to do this.

Thanks in advance.

===== EDIT =====

Here is the architecture of the app.

The main app frontend on PHP CodeIgniter lets tag it as PHPCI
The chat app backend on NodeJs and SocketIO lets tag it as CHAT
The chat model data on Redist lets tag it as REDIST

So what i have now its PHPCI -> CHAT -> REDIST. That work just fine.

What i need is to distribute the application so i can have as many PHPCI or CHAT or REDIST i want, example

```
 PHPCI1    CHAT1
 PHPCI2 ->       -> REDIST1
 PHPCI3    CHAT2
```

Where the numbers represent instances not different apps.

So a User A connected to PHPCI1 can send a message to a user B connected on PHPCI3.

I think some queue in the middle of CHAT can handle this something like rabbitmq that can only use the SocketIO to deliver the messages to the client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're distributing the server load (and that's a requirement), I'd suggest adding a designated chat data server (usually an in-memory database or message queue) to handle chat state and message passing across edge servers.

[Redis](http://redis.io/) [Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) is ideal for this purpose, and can scale up to crazy levels on even a low-end machine.  The [Redis Cookbook](http://www.rediscookbook.org) has a [chapter](http://www.rediscookbook.org/pubsub_for_asynchronous_communication.html) on precisely this use case.

Comment: what approach to distribute redis will be the best, replication or cluster, i read that cluster its on alpha stage

Comment: You almost certainly won't have to distribute redis...  it's an unbelievably fast engine (for most purposes).  StackOverflow, for instance, [runs boards for its sites on 2 Redis instances](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/) (and they only have a second for redundancy).

The one time you don't want to distribute data is when you have shared state (like this case).  Eventually, when this has to scale, you should shard the databases by chatroom.  (For instance, hash the chatroom ID to pick a redis server, so chats never travel across servers.)

Answer (score -1):

If you set up the server-side of your chat app correctly, you shouldn't have to distribute socket.io. Since node.js is browser-based and doesn't require any client-side code (other than the resources downloaded from the webpage), it works automatically. With a webpage, the files required to run socket.io are temporarily downloaded to users when they are correctly included (just like with jQuery). If you are using node.js and socket.io to make an android app, the files should be included in your application when you distribute it, not separately.

In addition, if you wish to use two separate socket.io servers, you should be able to establish communication between the two by connecting them in a similar manner that a client connects to the server, but with a special parameter that lets the other server know that a server connected and it can respond and set a variable for the other server.

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question, please clarify it by adding what kind of application (the platform) you are referring to so I can help you better.

Comment: Blubberguy22 i add some information about the architecture. thanks